# Nice automatic graph arrangement?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

I have the following graph data:

```
gr={1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 7, 4 -> 8, 
    5 -> 9, 5 -> 2, 6 -> 10, 6 -> 11, 7 -> 12, 8 -> 13, 8 -> 14, 9 -> 12,
    9 -> 15, 10 -> 4, 11 -> 16, 11 -> 13, 12 -> 17, 12 -> 18, 13 -> 8, 
    13 -> 19, 14 -> 18, 14 -> 20, 15 -> 21, 15 -> 9, 16 -> 11, 16 -> 22, 
    17 -> 23, 18 -> 14, 18 -> 24, 19 -> 25, 19 -> 26, 20 -> 27, 20 -> 28,
    21 -> 23, 21 -> 25, 22 -> 15, 22 -> 29, 23 -> 30, 23 -> 31, 
    24 -> 31, 24 -> 32, 25 -> 33, 25 -> 21, 26 -> 20, 27 -> 34, 27 -> 33,
    28 -> 32, 29 -> 19, 30 -> 35, 31 -> 24, 31 -> 36, 32 -> 37, 
    32 -> 38, 33 -> 35, 33 -> 27, 34 -> 39, 34 -> 37, 35 -> 40, 35 -> 41,
    36 -> 41, 36 -> 42, 37 -> 43, 37 -> 34, 38 -> 42, 39 -> 44, 
    39 -> 45, 40 -> 39, 41 -> 36, 41 -> 46, 42 -> 47, 42 -> 48, 43 -> 49,
    43 -> 47, 44 -> 49, 45 -> 46, 45 -> 50, 46 -> 45, 46 -> 51, 
    47 -> 52, 47 -> 43, 48 -> 51, 49 -> 53, 49 -> 54, 50 -> 54, 50 -> 55,
    51 -> 56, 51 -> 57, 52 -> 58, 52 -> 56, 53 -> 58, 54 -> 50, 
    54 -> 59, 55 -> 60, 55 -> 61, 56 -> 62, 56 -> 52, 57 -> 55, 58 -> 63,
    58 -> 64, 59 -> 64, 59 -> 65, 60 -> 66, 60 -> 62, 61 -> 65, 
    62 -> 67, 62 -> 60, 63 -> 67, 64 -> 59, 64 -> 68, 65 -> 69, 65 -> 70,
    66 -> 71, 66 -> 69, 67 -> 72, 67 -> 73, 68 -> 73, 68 -> 74, 69 -> 3,
    69 -> 66, 70 -> 74, 71 -> 75, 71 -> 76, 72 -> 71, 73 -> 68, 
    73 -> 77, 74 -> 1, 74 -> 78, 75 -> 6, 76 -> 77, 76 -> 16, 77 -> 76, 
    77 -> 79, 78 -> 79, 79 -> 5, 79 -> 80, 80 -> 22};
```

Trying to display the graph, we get from the default function:

```
Graph[gr]
```

> [image]

Here we can vaguely see that there are some toroidal features going on. However, the graph is rather busy and not really illuminating. How can I use Mathematica to let it automatically make the geometric features of the graph more clear (without assigning coordinates to vertices by hand)? Ideally, I would prefer the graph to fill out a volume, with an option to click and drag to rotate and zoom. Maybe one can even make the background features half transparent while the foreground is solid (to improve perspective)? Thanks for any suggestion!

*EDIT:*

[bill s](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1783/bill-s) suggested to look at `GraphPlot`, which led me to `GraphPlot3D`. Currently I have:

```
GraphPlot3D[gr, EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Arrow[#1, 0.01], Cylinder[#1, .03]} &), 
VertexRenderingFunction -> ({ColorData["Atoms"][ RandomInteger[{1, 117}]], Sphere[#1, .15]} &), 
PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 20]]]
```

> [image]

This is close to what I imagined. However, the arrows are kind of ugly and too large. I would also prefer to get rid of the surrounding box. Any quick way to fix the arrows and remove the box?

Comment: Try GraphPlot. It has options for the following layouts: {RadialDrawing, SpringEmbedding, SpringElectricalEmbedding, 
  LinearEmbedding, CircularEmbedding, RandomEmbedding, 
  HighDimensionalEmbedding}

Comment: @bills Thanks! I will give it a try.

Comment: Replace `Arrow[#1, 0.01]` with `{Arrowheads[0.02], Arrow[#1, 0.01]}`, and add the option `Boxed -> False` to the `GraphPlot3D`.

Comment: You could also try Graph3D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *do not* need the obsolete `GraphPlot`. The newer `Graph` and `Graph3D` have the same layouts and more. See [`GraphLayout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphLayout.html).

For your data,

```
Graph3D[gr]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also, check out the `"HighDimensionalEmbedding"` [`GraphLayout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphLayout.html) and its suboptions. It lays out the graph in higher dimensions and projects the coordinates back to 2D or 3D.

Answer (score 2):

Try GraphPlot. It has options for several ways of automatically laying out the vertices, including RadialDrawing, SpringEmbedding, SpringElectricalEmbedding, LinearEmbedding, CircularEmbedding, RandomEmbedding, and HighDimensionalEmbedding. For example,here's one:

```
GraphPlot[gr, Method -> "LayeredDrawing"]
```

[image]

Comment: I updated the question a little.

Answer (score 2):

`LayeredGraphPlot[]` might work for you as well:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Given the data, `gr`, it might be a good idea to show the multi-edges in a 3D graph plot with "SpringEmbedding":

```
GraphPlot3D[gr, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> (If [Length[#1] > 2, {Red, Line[#1]}, 
     Line[#1]] &), Method -> "SpringEmbedding", 
 BoxStyle -> Directive[Dashed], Boxed -> True]
```

[image]